# Convergence curve of optimization in Python

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I am using Python for optimization using pyomo library. I need to obtain the convergence curve from my solver. I am using ipopt solver for a non-linear optimization problem.

The objective is to check the convergence of the obtained solution. I would like to check the performance of different solvers for my problem. I believe obtaining a curve of convergence from the iteration data would be useful for the purpose.

I went through the documentation of the solver I am using currently from [this website](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/classIpopt_1_1ConvergenceCheck.html).

But I do not know how to use this information to obtain the curve of convergence or the iteration data.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this task.

Comment: Please, add more details, some context and show what you've come up with so far.

Comment: @go2nirvana Thank you for your comment. I have added more details to the post to describe my problem. Kindly go through.